# can someone explain the change to bulkDelete (discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

Here is the code I have right now

```js
module.exports ={
    name:'purge',
    description:'Clears the number of messages you set in a seccond ARG.',
    aliases:['clear','nuke'],
    execute(msg, args)
    {
        if(!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            return msg.reply("You do not have permission to run this command").then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
        }

        if (!isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <= 0) {
            return msg.reply("That is not a number").then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
        }

        if(!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
            return msg.reply("Sorry I can't messages please make sure i have the correct permissions").then(msg => msg.delete());
        }

        let deleteAmount;

        if(parseInt(args[0]) > 100) {
            deleteAmount = 100;
        } else {
            deleteAmount = parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        msg.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
(node:25048) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [MESSAGE_BULK_DELETE_TYPE]: The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.
    at TextChannel.bulkDelete (C:\StrangeOccBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:364:11)
    at Object.execute (C:\StrangeOccBot\commands\purge.js:27:21)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\StrangeOccBot\index.js:46:39)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\StrangeOccBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\StrangeOccBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\StrangeOccBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure if an `int` is still the way to do it with `bulkDelete()`
but as far as I know, you can fetch messages in a channel and pass those to the method!

```js
msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: deleteAmount }).then(messages => {
  msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(deleted => {
    msg.channel.send(`${deleted.size} messages pruged!`).then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
  })
})
```

This is the way how I have done it for the last few times I created functions like what you try to archive.
Also you can add `.catch()` methods to the `.then()` methods so you can check if something went wrong or not!

Edit: I changed your code a little bit especially at the end so you have an idea how I would have done it to archive what you wanna archive

```js
module.exports ={
  name:'purge',
  description:'Clears the number of messages you set in a seccond ARG.',
  aliases:['clear','nuke'],
  execute(msg, args) {

    if (!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        return msg.reply("You do not have permission to run this command").then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
    }

    if (!msg.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
      return msg.reply("Sorry I can't messages please make sure i have the correct permissions").then(msg => msg.delete());
    }

    if (!isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <= 0) {
      return msg.reply("That is not a number").then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
    }

    // I changed this slightly to how I would do it!
    let deleteAmount = 100;
    if (parseInt(args[0]) < 100) {
      deleteAmount = parseInt(args[0])
    }

    // If I'm not mistaken, the bulkDelete() method also works with fetched messages in an variable.
    // To archive this, you can use `msg.channel.messages.fetch()` as I will show below!
    // Ofcourse I did not use the .catch() method, so if something isn't correctly done it can cause issues!
    msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: deleteAmount }).then(messages => {
      msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages).then(deleted => {
        msg.reply(`${deleted.size} messages pruged!`).then(msg => msg.delete(5000));
      })
    })

  }
}
```